# Matplotlib captures wrong mouse coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

The goal is to click my mouse twice on an image and retrieve 2 coordinates. The code for doing so:

```
class ImageListener(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.coordinates = []

def onclick(self, event):
    print(event.x, event.y)
    self.coordinates.extend([event.x, event.y])

def show_image(self, img, close=True):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.imshow(img)
    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.onclick)
    while len(self.coordinates) < 3:
        plt.waitforbuttonpress(0)
    if close:
        plt.close(fig)

    fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
```

However, the coordinates that are captured are wrong. In the following image, my mouse is at (700,333) when I clicked. (Mouse disappeared during screenshot). Instead, (514, 154) is captured.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you are using `event.x` and `event.y`:

- x: x position - pixels from left of canvas
- y: y position - pixels from bottom of canvas

If you want the coord of mouse in data coords, you should use:

- xdata: x coord of mouse in data coords
- ydata: y coord of mouse in data coords

Refer to [doc](https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html).